# Stitch 2 mesh parts like in the UV stiching function

Tags: mesh, workflow

I don't know how to 'stitch' these two meshes together. I don't mean a 'bridge', I want the Foot moved correctly into the socket: There is a stitch function for UV maps that does exactly what I want (see the video: https://youtu.be/42XCrtxvhyM?t=519)

[image: i want to stitch that]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the loops match, you can **turn on snapping and auto merge** in Edit Mode to do this:

[image: Just an image]

1. Turn on snapping (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Set snapping mode to vertex (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
3. Turn on auto merge

Then move the part of the mesh:

[image]