# How to glue one selected face of a mesh precisely to a selected face on another mesh?

Tags: faces

I found some sort of answer to the question here, but did not understand the procedure at all. May be some on can help me understand it.

I have one mesh with a face of it selected and I want to "glue" that face to a selected face on a different mesh. For example, suppose two cubes are facing each other and I want to glue the faces that are facing each other to one another, or suppose I am modeling a starship. The wings are one mesh, and the body is another mesh. Now I want to connect the body and the wings  permanently at a very specific place on each. I thought to choose the faces on the wing mesh and on the body mesh that should be glued together and then blender glues them.

Something like this.

Comment: I can't see your links. If your purpose is to make an animation i suggest to look at [parenting objects](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-do-i-parent-objects). If instead is a precision modeling problem (ex. the wing is not flat) look for [snapping to surface and rotate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_TIY7QyeV8)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30354/1853

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use 'Snap to face' to place object, and then you could join them into single mesh if you wish.

[image]

Comment: You should also mention to remove doubles just in case there are any.

Answer (score 1):

If the face on the wing is about the almost exactly the same size, and in almost exactly the same position, snapping one face to another may work as Daniil suggested might work. If the two faces you want to "glue" together are **not** almost exactly the same size, nor almost exactly in the same position, or the geometry does not work satisfactorily when you try to join them, you will need to add new geometry on the one mesh, or the other, or both. A more exact answer is going to vary depending upon exactly what mesh is to be attached to which other mesh, and at which faces on the respective faces, and perhaps other considerations.

Depending on the exact faces to be joined, in some instances the method linked to in cegaton's comment is another way this can be achieved.

And there may be considerations which make joining the two meshes inadvisable, for example, if the wing needs to be movable relative to the body mesh.