# How to snap two mesh

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms, snapping

I have two mesh that are not aligned to the grid. How an I snap and merge these two shapes?

The first one is a cylinder, the second is a half sphere. They are at slightly different angles, but they both have the same number of vertices. If possible I would like to merge each matching vertex.

Comment: See [answer to similar question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30342/stitch-2-mesh-parts-like-in-the-uv-stiching-function/30354#30354) - To work with their vertex, meshes must be in the same object.

Comment: Both Mesh are the same object. The link is very helpful, but I'm still having trouble aligning the circles flat face with the cylinders flat face. Is there a way to align both flat ends to the same plane?

Comment: Are they at same axis ?!

Comment: try this addon : http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Align_by_faces

Comment: Yes, there is a built-in funtion.. see [(another) related answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/539/snap-object-on-top-of-surface-of-other-object) or [this videotutorial](http://oneminutevideotutorials.com/snap-object-to-the-face-of-another-object-in-blender-2-7/)

Comment: @Carlo The videotutorial did the trick! Thanks for the help!